# Best/common practices for website transfer (what time of day?)

Tags: web

Basically, my question is to get a feel for what time of day you do things like DNS transfers when moving sites across servers, and provide updates to sites. Does anyone do this during the day, or do most developers do this at night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think different approaches can be valid, depending on your situation, the actual change to be performed, how often a change happens and what your users expect.

If you do it **during the day**, you potentially have a longer time to fix issues if there are any, including if they are issues that need to be dealt with your service provider (which might be more responsive during business hours than at night or during week-ends).

If you enjoy working **at night or during week-ends** and you don't rely on any service provider to solve any issue related to the move/migration you're asking about, doing it at this time might be less disruptive to your users.

But all that also depends on **who are your actual users**.  More and more users are spread throughout the globe and can interact with your sites at any time of day or night.

Common systems administration practice, when dealing with big changes or migrations, usually recommends not doing it just before off-time (be it night, or week-end, or holidays), unless you're sure that you (or the team) is available to work to fix issues.  Basically, you need to plan for issues, because they always happen.

Something else to consider is any **SLA** you, or your company, might have with the users.  In that case, you might need to perform your maintenance action outside of business hours, or with provisional notice, or risking any penalty to be applied.

A proper answer to the question you're asking really depends on your situation and the business you're in.